# Query Collection In Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

can you please let me know how to filter the item in a collection in graph Api?

**Scenario**
Iam storing the Filter Value in a collection, and again have to filter my Library Data's with the Collection Values to display the Metadata.

Comment: Hello, would you share the request you are making to graph and what resource you want to query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.